# Как сделать блок изображений в виде колоды карт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

Есть, допустим, блок с изображениями:

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/00ff00">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/c009ff/ff0000">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/0000ff/000fff">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/dd00ff/000000">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/0d00ff/fff000">
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы он выглядел, как пачка фото, где одно под другим и немного выглядывают края, похожим на колоду карт? Выглядывают из под первого фото правый и нижний края второго например на `10px`, а из-под второго третий и т.д.

> Если можно, без js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Веером**

```css
.items {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 200% 0;
  outline: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.item:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/140x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/140x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/140x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/140x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/140x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http:placehold.it/140x200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
.card {
  display:inline-block;
  width:144px;
  height:209px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.clubs_10 {
  background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hayeah/playing-cards-assets/master/png/10_of_clubs.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:lightgrey;
}
.diamonds_king {
  background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hayeah/playing-cards-assets/master/png/king_of_diamonds.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  margin-left:-136px;
  margin-bottom:-10px;
}
.hearts_queen {
  background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hayeah/playing-cards-assets/master/png/queen_of_hearts.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  margin-left:-136px;
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card clubs_10"></div>
<div class="card diamonds_king"></div>
<div class="card hearts_queen"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: #fff;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

img:nth-child(2) {top: 10px;left: 10px;}
img:nth-child(3) {top: 20px;left: 20px;}
img:nth-child(4) {top: 30px;left: 30px;}
img:nth-child(5) {top: 40px;left: 40px;}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/00ff00">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/c009ff/ff0000">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/0000ff/000fff">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/dd00ff/000000">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/0d00ff/fff000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### SVG анимация развертывания веером карт

Используется

```
<animateMotion 
           dur="2s"
           begin="svg1.click"
           repeatCount="1"
           rotate="auto"
            keyPoints="0.3;0.54"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            fill="freeze"
            calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#p1"/>
      </animateMotion>
```

Как далеко повернется карта при разворачивании обеспечивают два атрибута

```
keyPoints="0.3;0.54" Определяет поворот от угла `30` до `54`
keyTimes="0;1"
```

*анимация после клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="150 0 500 500" style="border:1px solid" >  
         
<text x="200" y="50" font-size="24px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">Click me! </text>

<path id="p1" d="M50 500 A350 350 0 0 1 750 500" fill="none" stroke="none" />
<g >
  <image  y="0" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Ahn.jpg" width="110px" height="162px">
  <animateMotion 
           dur="0.1s"
           begin="svg1.click"
           repeatCount="1"
           rotate="auto"
            keyPoints="0.3;0.3"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            fill="freeze">
            <mpath xlink:href="#p1"/>
      </animateMotion> 
</image>  
 <image  y="0" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIWlv.jpg" width="110px" height="162px">
   <animateMotion 
           dur="2s"
           begin="svg1.click"
           repeatCount="1"
           rotate="auto"
            keyPoints="0.3;0.36"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            fill="freeze"
            calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#p1"/>
      </animateMotion>
</image>  
</g> 
<image  y="0" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVVaa.jpg" width="110px" height="162px">
   <animateMotion 
           dur="2s"
           begin="svg1.click"
           repeatCount="1"
           rotate="auto"
            keyPoints="0.3;0.42"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            fill="freeze"
            calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#p1"/>
      </animateMotion>
</image>  
<image  y="0" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIWlv.jpg" width="110px" height="162px">
   <animateMotion 
           dur="2s"
           begin="svg1.click"
           repeatCount="1"
           rotate="auto"
            keyPoints="0.3;0.48"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            fill="freeze"
            calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#p1"/>
      </animateMotion>
</image>   
  <image  y="0" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Ahn.jpg" width="110px" height="162px">
   <animateMotion 
           dur="2s"
           begin="svg1.click"
           repeatCount="1"
           rotate="auto"
            keyPoints="0.3;0.54"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            fill="freeze"
            calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#p1"/>
      </animateMotion>
</image>   
    <image  y="0" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Ahn.jpg" width="110px" height="162px">
   <animateMotion 
           dur="2s"
           begin="svg1.click"
           repeatCount="1"
           rotate="auto"
            keyPoints="0.3;0.6"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            fill="freeze"
            calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#p1"/>
      </animateMotion>
</image>  

  
</svg>
```