# Анимация раскрытия веера карт

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать анимацию на js при наведении на блоки.
Начальное положение блоков на рисунке 1, конечное, приблизительно, на рисунке 2.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Comment: Они должны выпрямиться и распределиться? Как заданы первоначальные позиция и угол поворота каждого элемента?

Comment: и перевернуться, как я понял

Comment: Еще и развернуться? 3D эффекты? А просто замены изображения рубашки на изображение "лица" карты не достаточно?

Comment: @Leonid
Мне нужно, чтобы блоки просто стояли веером картинкой вперед и при наведении просто выстроились в ряд, так же картинкой вперед.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/904634/308951  так может быть ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Раз

```js
const deck = document.querySelector('.deck')
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.deck__card')
const middle = Math.floor(cards.length / 2)

const animationDuration = 0.7
let isRunning = false

deck.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  if (isRunning) return
  isRunning = true

  cards.forEach((c, i) => {
    c.style.transition = animationDuration + 's'
    c.style.transform = `translateX(240px) translateY(15px) rotateZ(30deg)`
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    cards.forEach((c, i) => {
      const tx = i * 50 + Math.random() * 20
      const e = i == 0 || i == cards.length - 1 ? 15 : 0
      const ty = i < middle ? -i * 14 + e : (i - cards.length + 1) * 14 + e
      const rz = i * 7

      setData(c, 240 - tx, ty, 30 - rz)
      transform(c, c.dataset.tx, c.dataset.ty, c.dataset.rz, 0)
    })
  }, animationDuration * 1000)

  setTimeout(() => {
    cards.forEach((c, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const tx = +c.dataset.tx - (10 + Math.random() * 40)
        const ty = +c.dataset.ty + (Math.random() * 10)
        transform(c, tx, ty, c.dataset.rz, -180)
        if (i == cards.length - 1) isRunning = false
      }, 80 * i)
    })
  }, (animationDuration + 0.05) * 1000 * 2)
})

deck.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler)

function mouseLeaveHandler(e) {
  if (isRunning) return

  cards.forEach(c => transform(c, +c.dataset.tx, c.dataset.ty, c.dataset.rz, 0))

  setTimeout(
    () => cards.forEach((c, i) => transform(c, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    animationDuration * 1000
  )
}

function transform(el, tx, ty, rz, ry = 0) {
  el.style.transform = `
    translateX(${tx}px)
    translateY(${ty}px)
    rotateZ(${rz}deg)
    rotateY(${ry}deg)`
}

function setData(el, tx, ty, rz) {
  el.dataset.tx = tx
  el.dataset.ty = ty
  el.dataset.rz = rz
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.deck {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  list-style: none;
}

.deck__card {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  display: grid;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.4);
}

.deck__card>* {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.deck__card__front {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/12/18/38/treasure-2497813_960_720.png);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.deck__card__back {
  background-color: #212121;
  background-image: url(https://static.warthunder.ru/upload/image/!2015/August/roger_01.png);
}
```

```html
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="deck__card">
    <div class="deck__card__front"></div>
    <div class="deck__card__back"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Два

```css
:root {
  --card-height: 250px;
  --card-width: 150px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  height: var(--card-height);
  width: var(--card-width);
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  background-image: url(https://cdn131.picsart.com/276403626017211.png?type=webp&to=min&r=1024);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 140%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--card-width) * 3 - 160%)) translateY(5%) rotateZ(-30deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.02s;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--card-width) * 2 - 110%)) translateY(-12%) rotateZ(-20deg);
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.04s;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--card-width) * 1 - 60%)) translateY(-22%) rotateZ(-10deg);
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.06s;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--card-width) * -1 + 60%)) translateY(-22%) rotateZ(10deg);
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.08s;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--card-width) * -2 + 110%)) translateY(-12%) rotateZ(20deg);
}

li:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--card-width) * -3 + 160%)) translateY(5%) rotateZ(30deg);
}

ul:hover>li {
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ху-фо
Это слишком круто для меня)
Мне нужно, чтобы блоки просто стояли веером картинкой вперед и при наведении просто выстроились в ряд, также картинкой вперед.

Comment: @ВикторБ не понял. Начальное состояние - 6 карт веером? И при наведении эти 6 карт должны просто стать в ряд?

Comment: Да. Почему то сообщение обрезалось.

Comment: @ВикторБ добавил вариант

Comment: Первый вариант, красив, ничего не скажешь... Но на кой JS...???  Когда было бы достаточно анимации css... Хотя красиво... **`+`**

Comment: @Air почему нет? писать кучу кейфреймов как-то не очень хотелось.

Comment: @hu-fo, ок............................

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 11):

Вот вариант с переменными:

```css
.hand {
  transform: translate(calc(50vw - 200px), calc(50vh - 50px));
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
.hand div {
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.hand div:hover {
  transform:translate(0,-9px);
}
.hand div:after, .hand div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at center, wheat, steelblue);
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 76px;
    width: 50px;
    --rot: 0deg;
    transform: translate(175px) rotatez(calc(var(--i) * 15deg)) rotatey(var(--rot));
    transform-origin: 50% 200%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.hand div:after  {
    content: attr(data-card);
    line-height: 76px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: wheat;
    --rot: 180deg;
}
.hand:hover div:after, .hand:hover div:before {
  transform: translate(175px) translate(calc(var(--i) * 55px), 0) 
      rotatez(0) rotatey(calc(180deg + var(--rot)));
}
```

```html
<div class="hand">
  <div data-card="♠️A" style="--i:-2.5"></div>
  <div data-card="♠️K" style="--i:-1.5"></div>
  <div data-card="♠️Q" style="--i:-0.5"></div>
  <div data-card="♠️J" style="--i: 0.5"></div>
  <div data-card="♠️10" style="--i: 1.5"></div>
  <div data-card="♠️9" style="--i: 2.5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: вот это круто - главное без js

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Это сильно )))

Comment: действительно круто, но мне больше подходит ответ выше)